# Why does BooleanToVisibilityConverter seem to return "Hidden" (not "Collapsed") when passed DependencyProperty.UnsetValue?

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, binding, dependency-properties

I've made a simple viewer of XAML documents that use a number of our own value converters, as well as built in ones, of course. It is expected behavior that there are DependencyProperty.UnsetValue bindings present.

I'm encountering a problem where the resulting view of my document acts like the built-in BooleanToVisibilityConverter is returning "Hidden" in that situation. I had expected it to act as if false was the value passed in. I was not even aware that "Hidden" was a possible result, and no such thing is mentioned in the [MS docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx).

Since I don't want to be changing the documents themselves to suit, I'm not planning to make a converter of my own that behaves as I expect. Any ideas out there to get what I want here, or even confirmation that what I'm seeing makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

The `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` returns a `Visibility`. If you [consult the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx), you will find that `Hidden` is a valid value. A binding that results in `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` will not attempt to convert this value via its associated converter. It effectively turns off the binding, i.e. it should have the same result as if the binding was not present at all.

In this case, your `Hidden` value will be coming from elsewhere. To understand the mechanism for determining a dependency property value, look at the documentation regarding [dependency property precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx). In your case, it is most likely an inherited, or default value (but that is just a guess!)

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, I understand that "Hidden" is a valid Visibility value; I was confused because it isn't (as far as I know) a valid result of the BooleanToVisibilityConverter - however your explanation that it isn't coming from there makes sense. I'm confused, though, because I can see in the debugger that in similar situations our own value converters ARE getting called with the paramater equalling DependencyProperty.UnsetValue. Anyways, I'll look at the precedence docs you linked later today when i get time.

Comment: I looked, but still don't see what's really going on in my specific case. I'll make a minimal test case next month when the pressure is off here at work.